# How to resolve ZeroDivisionError while trying to update one dataframe column value based on multiple / two dataframe column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Scores | Correct | Incorrect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

I am trying to update and normalize the 'Scores" column in such a way that

```
df['Scores'] = df['Scores'] / (df['Correct']+df['Incorrect])
```

But there may be some columns that can cause ZeroDivisionError as you can see in the second row of the dataframe. So I used this code but it still throws ZeroDivisionError:

```
df['Scores'] = np.where(((df['Correct']+df['Incorrect])>0), df['Scores'] / (df['Correct']+df['Incorrect]), df['Scores'])
```

What can I do in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should also work. I think the problem is with the placement of your code if you are placing it inside a loop or something. Please make sure that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Series.div` or change `>0` to `!=0` in your `np.where`

```py
df['Scores'] = df['Scores'].div(df['Correct']+df['Incorrect'])
# or
df['Scores'] = np.where(((df['Correct']+df['Incorrect'])!=0), df['Scores'] / (df['Correct']+df['Incorrect']), df['Scores'])
```